# Applying grey level morphological close in ImageJ

Tags: image

I have an assignment that asks me to apply a grey level morphological close to an image using imageJ. I don't think I'm supposed to implement a filter from scratch, but I can't find any built in functions that would help me. Am I missing something?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are binary operations. Dilate, open, close. That works on binary images though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are missing something :)
If you go to `Process--> Morphology --> Gray Morphology` you can define a `Close` operation with various mask shapes and sizes.

It'll work with any gray-scale image.

---

By the way, I would recommend using [Fiji](https://fiji.sc/) which is only `ImageJ` (Fiji Is Just ImageJ : FIJI) with automatic packages updates.